# Do two similar domain names affect SEO negatively?

Tags: seo, multiple-domains

I have one domain: `sport-clothing.com` and I want to create another shop (different content) with name `sportclothing.com`.

Will such similar domains affect SEO of both negatively?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Search engines will consider these two domains as different for SEO (because of the different URL) even if these two websites:

- have a similar URL
- belong to you
- have a similar theme (*sport clothing* in your case)

Therefore, if you don't use duplicate content, there is no reason why one domain can affect negatively SEO of the other.

Answer (score 5):

There are lots of websites with similar domains out there so this won't be an issue. You will only run into issues if you use duplicate content on these two sites (which the domains suggest is probable). If you plan on the second site being a clone, or a slightly different version of the first, you will have duplicate content issue which *will* hurt the second site for sure and possibly hurt the first one as well.